# Limiting sidebar TOC depth in Sphinx HTML builder

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm trying to limit the depth of sidebar toc generated by Sphinx HTML Biulder. I tried to change localsidebar.html with my own but I couldn't find any hints in the [documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html), just the deprecated options. `{{ toc }}` contains rendered local toc but there's no info about how to work with it before it gets rendered.

Comment: Have you had any success so far? I have the same question.

Comment: @creimers unfortunately no.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the following line at the top of the file:

```
:tocdepth: <n>
```

with `<n>` being the depth you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the best sidebar results by setting maxdepth in the theme customizations in _templates/layout.html.  No extra directive options are needed in the rst toctree file hierarchy.

```
{%- block sidebartoc %}
    {{ toctree(collapse=False,maxdepth=2) }}
{%- endblock %}
```